# Terminal stuck, cannot enter git commands after npm install

Tags: npm, build, npm-install, parcel

I have cloned a GitHub repo and ran **npm install** as usual (I have it installed globally)
For some reason when I run **start**, the terminal gets stuck in **build**, though it did build with **parcel** (dist folders are created), also I can see the live server page. I can code, I can update.

The problem is that the terminal is stuck on the error message below and I have to start a new terminal every time.

[error message on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9r8t.png)

```
Building...(node:14216) ExperimentalWarning: Package name self resolution is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
/ Building CSSPlugin.js...(node:8680) ExperimentalWarning: Package name self resolution is an experimental feature. This feature 
could change at any time
- Building bundle-url.js...(node:14220) ExperimentalWarning: Package name self resolution is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
```

Any idea why I am getting this and how to get rid of it?
Obs.: I have attempted to delete the folder and clone again, the same issue when running **npm start** for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same behaviour on Node.js v13.9.0.

After [updating Node.js to latest stable version](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version), the warning message is gone and everything works fine.